# Reading industrial magnetic length sensor (DRO)

Tags: arduino, sensor, industrial

My brother broke his LCD display on his saw, it is a simple display put on conductive silicon strip showing numbers and some status icons.

They priced the replacement for about 500$, which is kind of lot in our country.

So i thought that since the only important function is to measure length, that i take the sensor connected to the display, find the documentation and use it with arduino. 
But the documentation cant be found because it is custom made sensor by the company. It has five wires and the display was powered by one AAA battery.

Before i dive into debugging with logic probe, did anyone used that sensor in his project?

Thanks, im also uploading images of sensor and PCB.

[image: Sensor]
[image: Label of display]
[image: PCB]

Comment: Is replacing the LCD an option? I think you'll find that the PCB is feeding out signals to the sensor otherwise it wouldn't need so many wire cores.

Comment: No idea, it is possible. But i dont think i can find a compatible display.

Comment: You might be able to find a compatible display on eBay. The sensor appears to be a magnetic type- it may have a quadrature ~ 1V sinusoidal (analog-ish) output. Or not.

Comment: [This](https://www.siko-global.com/adbimage/1952/asset_original/datenblatt-ls100.pdf) may be of help. It seems like the "LS100" is pretty similar to what you have. And, indeed, it has quadrature 1Vss sinusodial output.

Comment: Is there any other labelling on the sensor itself?

Comment: They have 'digital' sensors too, e.g. [this one](https://www.siko-global.com/de-de/produkte/magline-magnetische-laengen-und-winkelmessung/magnetische-sensoren/msk210-linear), which connect via 4 wires: black=GND, brown=V+, red=A, orange=B. These output your regular binary quadrature signal on A and B. Can you still measure what voltage the display unit provides to the sensor?

Comment: Shielding wire is truly connected to black wire, but i had no success when i tried to connect it to 5V a examining it with my logic probe... 

I will try to order "DRO Magnetic Remote Digital Readout" ruler for 20$ from aliexpress and see how it goes. Hope ill be able to replace the original with it since i have no better plan.